# summarize the results of a cluster from Centroids

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining

I'm performing a **cluster analysis** on the iris dataset using `WEKA`. I would like to know how I can summarize the results of a cluster using the values that are given for the centroids. I got the following results but I'm not sure how I can make a conclusion using the figures:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A centroid is a point that minimizes some distance to all points in the cluster. In this case, it is also the **mean** of all instances in the cluster and thus, is a kind of representative of those instances, e.g., you could say

> [sepallength=5.8885, sepalwidth=2.7377, petallength=4.3967,
>   petalwidth=1.418]

is the **mean** or **prototype** of cluster #1 (the average flower in #1).

Note, however, that the Iris dataset has labels and they don't coincide with the results you show (and they shouldn't, in general). So you can't *classify* them into setosa, virginica or versicolor. Those 3 clusters have no intrinsic *class* or *name*.